# A cowboy enters and leaves town

Tags: lateral-thinking

1880, August the first, Jones is a cowboy. and he is ready to settle down and look for a house to stay in. He's been wandering Texas for quite some time now. He doesn't have much with him - only a *few* thousand dollars, some extra clothes and his horse.
So when he's looking for a house, he wants a house with a stable also.

**Day 1)**
He enters a town on Sunday at night. It's too dark to see anything so Jones decides to rent a room for the night and look for a house the next day.

*And so he does ...*

**Day 2)**
He looks around for a house but finds a bar, he gets drawn into the bar and Jones is ready to make some new friends. Bill becomes his new drinking partner. 
They drink all day and so Jones doesn't find a house, so he has to rent another room for the night.

*And so he does ...*

**Day 3)**
Jones knows that Bill is back at the bar so he's avoiding the bar today.
During his search for a house he finds a casino. Jones has never been to a casino, so he is tempted to enter the casino. He does enter eventually. 
He stays all day at the casino and wastes about 90% of his money there.
At the end of the day, Jones doesn't find a house once more. So he has to rent a room for the night.

*And so he does ...*

**Day 4)**
Jones wakes up broke, almost all of his money is gone. He cannot afford a house anymore.
Jones buys some food with his last bit of money and leaves town on Sunday.

*And so he does ...*

> **Question**: How is it possible that he enters the town on Sunday and leaves the town on Sunday when only 4 days have passed?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: You might want to change "thousand" to a more reasonable amount of money a cowboy might actually be carrying in 1880.  Having that much cash would likely have meant that he left the bar in a pine box.  Even saying he only had a few hundred left over would mean he was pretty well off.

Comment: Darn! I was sure he had lunch, gunned someone down in the street, and then departed...oh, sorry - wrong joke! :-)

Comment: @Warlord 099: Thanks for the spoiler...

Comment: @Warlord099 thanks for spoiling it.. not nice

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Sunday is the name of his horse. He enters and leaves the town (riding) on Sunday.

Comment: Then there is a mistake in the riddle... Some capitals letters are missing ! But nice one !

Comment: His horse is on the phone to Monday.  Tuesday's on the phone to me.

Comment: It's nice though that August 1, 1880 was actually a Sunday.

Answer (score 7):

Somewhat ridiculous answer, but could be possible... maybe

> Jones is an incarnation of [the Doctor](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/The_Doctor_(Doctor_Who)) and goes to 1880 to rent a buy a house, on some other day than Sunday. He leaves the T.A.R.D.I.S. in town, gets a horse, and rides into the town on a Sunday. He stays four days, uses the T.A.R.D.I.S. to go back or forwards to a Sunday, and then leaves.

Creativity.

Comment: Creative but no :( Jones doesn't own a T.A.R.D.I.S.

Comment: Well, I knew the classic horse answer, but I didn't want to use it.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole Me too. :)

Comment: @Decypher - ehhhh...would you believe a ***DeLorean*** with a ***flux capacitor***?

Comment: @BobJarvis I totally would. Bought one myself ( on a 1:64 scale)

Answer (score 6):

> The horse gallops at a significant portion of the speed of light, so relativity causes him to advance from Sunday to Sunday in four days.

Answer (score 4):

> Bill roofied Jones and he woke up three days later without knowing how many days have passed.

Comment: Creative but no, roofies were created in 1957 I believe.

Comment: Time-travelling roofies? ;)

Comment: @Gigala So this is the *bill is the doctor* answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Sunday is the name of a road through - or, merely into - the town. (Similar answer to cpj's)

Answer (score 0):

Jones drank a few too many martinis at the casino, and mistook a near light speed train car for his hotel at the end of day three. the train then departed and ran for a just enough time for 3 days to pass in time relative to the town. Jones was only on the train for a few hours at most, depending on how incredibly advanced this train is.

Answer (score -2):

Jones Entered on Sunday and left the same day. According to Jones, he thought he lived in that town many days, lived a day and that is it for Jones